# Button on Django admin main page to show a custom template admin view

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I would to customize my Django admin site.

I need to add a button (for example on the top of main page...for example) to show an custom page where I need to have a google maps with some marker.

So:

- Is possibile to add a button somewhere in the main page admin site?
- When I press this button I need to show my admin custom page (a template with google maps).

I think that is possible because I already see something like this but I can't find something about this in Django documentation.

Links to Django documentation, tutorial or examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ allows to set custom admin pages and even more. Consider it for your task.

As for the django admin itself you can customize admin templates to add your custom page to the admin.